# Appending Data with Highcharts (real time updating chart)

Tags: javascript, highcharts

In terms of efficiency using Highcharts. If the server sends arrays of points (about 5,000 at a time). Is it more efficient to use the [addPoint](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series#addPoint) method and add each point? Or to contact the previous array with the new chuck and call [redraw()](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart.html#redraw)

- option 1:

`for(let point in newData) series.addPoint(point, redraw  = false)`

- option 2:

`oldData = oldData.concat(newData)`

Do Highcharts re-render the all the points or just the new portion?

Comment: I would say if you are adding 5k points each time it is probably better to use option2. How often are you sending these 5k chunks?

Comment: every 2-3 seconds

Comment: @wergeld - what are the difference between the 2 options? (like performance wise)

Comment: As @Nimrod007 said, the average case is 10-15K points, but it can go up to 100K points in some cases. Does Highcharts re-renders the new portion or the entire set when each iteration?

Comment: @Nimrod007, the difference would be your for each loop in option1 and then in option 2 letting highcharts handle the addition of the new points (with scaling of axis as needed). Think of it this way: option 1 - take point from loop add it to data, plot point, take next point from loop add it to data, plot point. option 2 - take data array, append to existing data array, plot set of data. Odds are that doing set operation would be faster. You can run a compare looking at process time for each and see if this is true.

Comment: @user2126373, every 2-3 seconds you generate 5k or 10-15k? I recommend trying each version out yourself and seeing what suites your data format (which you have not provided) and other chart options (flags, etc).

Comment: @wergeld - using the above option 1 is add point +  redraw = false, updated the question to better reflect that. so in both options we dont redraw the chat from scratch, just a different way to add the data and after all data is added (current chunk) we redraw

Comment: I agree with @wergeld. You should try the both solutions and see which one is faster. By the way: have you considered using `setData` on series?

Answer (score 1):

As @wergeld suggested, I tried both options.

The data looks like this: `[{x:1, y:2, step: 1}, {x:2, y:3, step: 2}...]` and I ran the same data size for a couple of times to get an average.

**Option 1 (addPoint)**

Code looks like:

`newData.forEach(el=> chart.series[0].addPoint(el, false, false, true))
 chart.redraw();`

And the results are:

```
 DataSize |   Seconds
 -------------------
 877      |   0.5 
 8770     |   1.5
 17540    |   8.5 
 87700    |   563
```

**Option 2 (setData / concat)**

Code looks like:

`chart.series[0].setData(oldData.concat(newData))`

And the results are:

```
 DataSize |   Seconds
 -------------------
 877      |   0.5 
 8770     |   1.85
 17540    |   3.4 
 87700    |   15 
 175400   |   25 
 877000   |   190
```

## Conclusion

So clearly, when the size of the data is getting larger than 10k per chunk of data, the `addPoint` method is getting significantly slower.